# How to add elements to a fixed size array in Java after the last non-null element?

Tags: java, arrays, string, null, indexing

So I have a String array with length 10. I add one or two values and the rest is still null. I want to be able to go back and add more values starting from the first non-null element. How do i get the index number? Currently my logic overwrites the array and starts from the 0 index. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about you post this logic of yours?

Comment: Go through the array until you find a null???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom method, that checks which is the last `null` element in the array and return it's index.

```
public int getTheIndexOfNull(String[] array) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
             result = i;
             break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What about `return i` and `return -1` instead of a `break`? Or at least `result = i; return i;`.

Comment: `return i; return -1` instead of a `break` ? Think again. :)

Comment: Definitely not. Think again. :)

Comment: Remove `result` variable and you will see.

Comment: This is equivalent to the one-liner `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, what about just using an `ArrayList<String>`? Internally, it does exactly what you want here: it has an `Object[]` where items are `null` after the current length, and it has an `int` saying what the next empty index is.

Answer (score 0):

The array length cannot changed after array creation. However you can always assign any value to any element"

```
String[] a = new String[10];
a[5] = "foo";
a[6] = "bar";
```

To find the first null element go in loop and assign the value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == null) {
        a[i] = s;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
        String[] yourArray = new String[10];
        yourArray[0] = "zero";
        yourArray[1] = "one";

        for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
            if(yourArray[i] == null){
                yourArray[i] = "youElemAfterFirstNonNullElem";
                break;
            }
        }
```